# Giving line features of same layer different colours

Tags: qgis, layers, style, line

I have one layer and there I have different lines. Imagine these lines are pathes of persons. So image a person x and y. And I now want to differ them by just watching on the different colours of the lines. Is this possible?

And please no solution with different layers. For sure that's possible but I cannot create a layer for each of the 50 persons.

So is there a way to differ styling in QGIS on one layer?

Comment: Does the data contain person IDs? Basically, can you distinguish between the lines from different people? Or is each line a different person anyway?

Comment: Well I create the lines on my own. And they can have their own ID's in the way I want to have them. And yes one person has n lines. I gonna have a look on the already given answer if that is working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, very simple:

Just use the Categorized Symbology.

If you do not have any attributes, you can just use $id as your "Column".

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Wow, this is an solution I was actually dreaming of. Exactly the way I needed it to be. I can also switch layer visibility in the layers. Great. But really hard to find such great solutions somehow. Or at least for me =) Also thanks for the pictures.